# Can Let's Encrypt distribute multiple certificates for a single domain name?

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt

Can we let Encrypt distribute multiple certificates for a single domain name? I mean all of them are valid at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check out the rate limit documentation:

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/

If you need to do so for testing, the staging API rate limit is much higher.

In fact, I’m working on a [home cloud system](https://ppl.family) and we’re building a kind of “inside out” cloud where the devices use [Greenlock](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js) and [Telebit](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/telebit.js) so that they each have their own certificate and connection rather than being behind a load balancer - exactly the kind of thing we couldn’t reasonably do without Let’s Encrypt.

Also, if you've got an application where you're sharing a domain among many hosts be sure to get your shared domains listed in the [Public Suffix List](https://github.com/publicsuffix/list) both for security and so you don't hit rate limits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, that is the functionality I am working on.

Comment: See the note I just added. You may need to get your shared domain listed in the PSL. Also, check out the device we're working on https://ppl.family. Would love to sell you one when they're ready if it interests you.